# remove a user control in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I have a control image in a user control. And I'm using a repeater to create several images list.

I have a button outside from the user control to delete image (per images).

I want to know, how can I make references to an specific row when I click in the button to delete the image.

This is the repetear:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ImageRepeater" runat="server" 
    onitemcommand="ImageRepeater_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <uc1:IVT_DisplayImage ID="IVT_DisplayImage1" runat="server" ImageURL="<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
            <asp:Button ID="RemoveDiplayImage" Text="Remove" runat="server" 
            CommandName="delete" 
            />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is the event ItemCommand:

```
protected void ImageRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "delete")
    {
        //????
    }
}
```

I want to know, how identify by code wich row (user control) I'm selecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `CommandArgument` to your button like `CommandArgument="<%# Container.ItemIndex %>"`.

This way, in the code; `e.CommandArgument` gives you the item number, with which you can get the item that you want.

**Note:** In fact instead of specifying `ItemIndex` as `CommandArgument`, you can use any Primary Key (Unique Identifier) from the DataSource that you bind to the repeater from where you will be able to get hold of the record directly from the list object (DataSource).

Comment: Sorry. Previously, I was under the impression of GridView and included GridViewRowIndex as CommandArgument. Updated the answer. Please check with this.